# Dynamic variables in Clojure libraries

Tags: clojure

TL;DR: Is the following a good pattern for a library?

```
(def ^{:dynamic true} *var*)
(defn my-fn [{:keys [var]}]
  (do-smth (or var *var*)))
```

--

Say I want to write a sentiment analysis library.

Is it good design in `get-sentiment` fn to accept optional sentiment labels but provide default one as dynamic var?

```
(def ^:dynamic *sentiment-level-labels*
  ["Very Negative" "Negative" "Neutral" "Positive" "Very Positive"])

;;...

(defn get-sentiment-scores
  "Takes text and gives back a 0 to 4 sentiment score for each sentences."
  [text]
  ;;...)

(defn get-sentiment 
  "Gives back a sentiment map with sentences scores, 
   average score, rounded score and labeled score.
   Can accepts custom sentiment level labels under :labels opt."
  [text & {:keys [labels]}]
  (let [scores (get-sentiment-scores text)
        average-score (get-average scores)
        rounded-score (Math/round average-score)
        label (get (or labels *sentiment-level-labels*) rounded-score)]
    {:scores scores
     :average-score average-score
     :rounded-score rounded-score
     :label label}))
```

Clojure library coding standards official page says:

> If you present an interface that implicitly passes a parameter via
>   dynamic binding (e.g. db in sql), also provide an identical interface
>   but with the parameter passed explicitly.

https://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards

In my example, I provided only one interface but with opt argument.

Is this okay? Are there better ways to handle this?

Thank you!

Comment: In my experience, having dynamic arguments /almost/ always causes more trouble than it saves down the line. You need a pretty compelling reason to have them and in this case I would definitely just make `*sentiment-level-labels*` a non-dynamic `default-sentiment-level-labels`. Note that clojure.java.jdbc  (like the example in the docs) used to have a dynamic default db argument but that was removed ages ago.

Comment: Thank you! I really like the "default-" prefix.

Comment: Would `*sentiment-level-labels` without closing ear muff would also be allright to visually mark that this value when present in a function is not passed in parameter? Or even `*default-sentiment-level-labels`? Thanks!

Comment: @leontalbot No, that is super gross and weird. Nobody uses `*` that way, and so nobody reading your code will understand the meaning you hope to convey.

Comment: Stuart Sierra has a good discussion of dynamic variables. It's titled "On the Perils of Dynamic Scope". You may be able to guess what his conclusions are. :-) Link: https://stuartsierra.com/2013/03/29/perils-of-dynamic-scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic vars are full or pitfalls. They push your API code towards implicit environmental coupling, and often force your calling code to add a lot of `(binding ...)` clauses, which kind of defeats the purpose of concision for using Dynamic vars in the first place. They also lead to tricky edge cases if control is passed from one thread to another.

In your case, I would recommend simply passing the labels in a `params` map argument:

```
(def default-sentiment-level-labels
  ["Very Negative" "Negative" "Neutral" "Positive" "Very Positive"])

(defn get-sentiment 
  "Gives back a sentiment map with sentences scores, 
   average score, rounded score and labeled score.
   Can accepts custom sentiment level labels under :labels opt."
  [text {:as params, :keys [labels] :or {labels default-sentiment-labels}}]
  ...))
```

Note that the usage of a map can be interesting, because a map is opaque to intermediaries: you can have various components of your algorithm read only from the `params` map the keys that concern them.

Comment: A map is opaque to intermediaries, and is a lovely solution to this problem. An *unrolled* map, though, as you use here with `& {...}` is a PITA to every intermediary, since they have to construct a map out of the unrolled keyword args, and deconstruct it back into unrolled keyword args to pass to the next layer. Much much better to simply take `[text {:as params ...}]` instead of `[text & {:as params ...}]`.

Comment: @amalloy My mistake, I fully agree with you about unrolled maps, and corrected my answer accordingly.